# sf plot, key not showing correctly R

Tags: r, plot, r-sf

I've been trying to plot a shapefile using `sf` package `plot` function but I get this:

(The shapefile can be found here: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AKMP9i549xESStN-R59UUU80OmkXy1XM)

```
sf <- st_read('fisiografia_cortado_disolve_gapis_des.shp')
plot(sf, lty = 0)
```

[image]

I can't display the key correctly. I've been playing with `par` function but I think I'm doing all wrong because nothing changes.

I tried:

```
par(mar = c(10,10,10,20))
```

and many other combinations (c(10,5,5,20), c(10,10,10,10)) but I think sf plots doesn't rely on `par` settings (forgive if I'm wrong).

I also tried to use the `key.size` attribute within the `plot` function but it only changes the width of the key (see the left image below) and if it is too big only the key is shown (right).

```
plot(sf, lty = 0, key.size = 1)
plot(sf, lty = 0, key.size = 10)
```

[image]

I'd like to show correctly the key and, if possible, change its size.

Anyone has gone through the same problem?

Comment: Including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question will increase your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: @jsb Thanks for the remark. Added details.

Comment: What package version are you using?

Comment: @jsta I'm using 0.5-5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the `oma` parameter of `par` to show the full label.

```
library(sf)

dt <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

par(oma = c(0, 0, 0, 4))
plot(dt["NAME"])
```

[image]

You can also use `key.size` as long as you give it a unit with `lcm()`. See https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf5.html#color-keys

```
par(oma = c(0, 0, 0, 0)) # just resetting par
plot(dt["NAME"], key.size = lcm(4))
```

[image]

Comment: You're right, I should have read all the `par` help vignette. Btw, do you know how does the `key.size` attribute should be used?

Comment: Added more detail on `key.size`.